# How to post data to server and capture response

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I'm new to web development and stucked at sending data to server. I have registration form and i want to send this data to server. I can send data from form tag using action and method attribute but it will return response in next page. So i read somewhere i have to use ajax to send data. I tried but i cannot send and capture data using script.

This is my reponse

> {"success":true}

**Html code**

```
<div class="form">
 <div class="formdetail">
    <h3>Individual Registration</h3>

<label for="fname"> Name</label><br>
<input type="text" size="40" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name.." required><br><br>



   <label for="phonenumber">Mobile Number</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="mobileno"  size="40" name="mobileno" type="tel" size="20"  maxlength="13" placeholder="Enter your mobile number..." type="number" required><br><br>


<label for="email">Email-Id</label><br>
<input type="text" size="40" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email-id..." required><br><br>



    <input type="date" id="dt" onchange="mydate1();" hidden/>
   <input type="text" id="ndt" name="dob" onclick="mydate();" hidden />
 <input type="button" Value="Date of Birth" onclick="mydate();" />

 <script>

 function mydate()
{
//alert("");
document.getElementById("dt").hidden=false;
document.getElementById("dob").hidden=true;
}
function mydate1()
{
 d=new Date(document.getElementById("dt").value);
 dt=d.getDate();
 mn=d.getMonth();
 mn++;
 yy=d.getFullYear();
 document.getElementById("dob").value=dt+"/"+mn+"/"+yy
 document.getElementById("dob").hidden=false;
 document.getElementById("dt").hidden=true;
 }

</script>
<br><br>
  <label for="address">Address</label><br>
<input type="text" id="address"  size="40" name="address" placeholder="Enter your address..." required><br><br>

<label for="country">Country</label><br>
<input type="text" id="country" size="40"  name="country" placeholder="Enter your country name....." required><br><br>

 <label for="State">State</label><br>
<input type="text" id="state" size="40" name="state" placeholder="Enter your state name....." required><br><br>

  <label for="city">City</label><br>
<input type="text" id="city" size="40" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city name....." required><br><br>
     <input type="hidden" name="category" value="Individual">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="someInput" onclick="ajax_post()"><br>

<a href="log1.html"><p class="small">Institute Registraion</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</form> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ajax_post(){
 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://smilestechno.000webhostapp.com/Register.php";


hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
    var resp = console.log(response);
    if (resp == "true") {

  }
}
hr.send("name="+ name + "&mobileno=" + mobileno + "&email=" + email + "&dob=" + dob + "&address=" + address + "&city=" + city + "&state=" + state + "&country=" + country );
document.getElementById("status").innerhtml = "processing";
}
```

Comment: What's the issue that you're facing?

Comment: it is not storing data on server when i m using script.. and i m confused how can i capture json object

Comment: If you are able to post data successfully then you might need to be looking at your backend api code (php) to handle the request! ('vars' will be part of your request body)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Is it just me, or you're missing the `<form ...` tag at the beginning?... I see that you *do* have the end tag `</form>`, though...

Answer (score 2):

you can not send variable in this format.

```
var vars = name+mobileno+email+dob+address+city+state+country;
```

Params must have a format like:

```
hr.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Code you need:

```
hr.send("name=" + name + "&monbileno=" + mobileno + ... );
```

You can use jquery to use ajax in a simple way.

Reference:

- xmlhttprequest https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
- jquery ajax https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery, it makes it easier. This is how it should be using just the *fname* and *email* as an example with jquery ajax:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="myActionUrl" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

$("#myForm").on("submit", function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); //this prevents the form to use default submit

   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: $(this).attr("action"), //this will use the form's action attribute
     data: {fname: $("#fname").val(), email: $("#email").val()},
     success: function(responseData){
      //do something here with responseData
     }
   });
});

</script>
```

Please replace the "myActionUrl" part with the url/file that processes your data.

The file can be some basic php file which stores the data into some database and returns or echoes something back so that you can use it within the "responseData" on the ajax success function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please call function like this

```
onclick="ajax_post()"
```

not

```
onclick="ajax_post"
```

You used getElementById but selected a name attribute
have to use

```
getElementById('fname').value;
```

not

```
getElementById('name').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i would recommend using jquery to accomplish this task.

this isthe client script

```
script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.js'></script>
  <!-- download the lates version -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 ajax_post(){
  var url = "https://smilestechno.000webhostapp.com/Register.php";
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var mobileno = $("#mobileno").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var dob = $("#dob").val();
  var address = $("#address").val();
  var city = $("#city").val();
  var state =  $("#state").val();
  var country = $("#country").val();

  var tmp = null;
   $.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'type': "POST",
    'global': false,
    'dataType': 'json',
    'url':url,
    'data':{name:name,mobileno:mobileno,email:email,dob:dob,address:address,city:city,state:state,country},
    'success': function (data) {
        tmp = data;
    }
});
return tmp; // you can access server response from this tmp variable
```

}

**Server side**

```
 <?php
  //get items as post inputs
   print_r($_POST[]);
  echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Comment: how to call this function in onlclick of submit... its showing ajax_post is not defined

Comment: please follow up the scripts to see that the js is included on the same file, if it fails u will need to restructure to use @Galanx answer  the post before mine